# Get the domain name in linux (C programming)

Tags: c, linux

other than getdomainname() is there any way to get the domain name on Linux without having to open and parse files in /etc?

Code is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `getdomainname()`?

Comment: it always returns "none" even when the domain is set

Comment: You're likely facing a configuration problem rather than a library one. You may want to post a similar question on Serverfault to try to determine why `getdomainname()` doesn't return what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char hn[254];
  char *dn;
  struct hostent *hp;

  gethostname(hn, 254);
  hp = gethostbyname(hn);
  dn = strchr(hp->h_name, '.');
  if ( dn != NULL ) {
    printf("%s\n", ++dn);
  }
  else {
    printf("No domain name available through gethostbyname().\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It seems that getdomainname() will only tell you a NIS or YP domain name, which you probably won't have set.  Querying for the full hostname with gethostbyname(), on the other hand, checks a variety of different sources (including DNS and /etc/hosts) to determine your canonical hostname.

Comment: No the best solution since the hostname not always has the domain name but good enough

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, Linux and some other systems have a [`getdomainname()` function](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setdomainname.2.html) which should do what you want, although this is [not part of the POSIX standard](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setdomainname.2.html#CONFORMING_TO).

Comment: Thanks, but if you read my question you can see that I am aware of that function

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but you and others who come here for an answer to the same question may value a reference to the documentation.

Comment: As the Linux manual page says ("getdomainname, setdomainname - get/set NIS domain name"), as well as other answers, this will get the NIS domain name, not the DNS domain name.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: ghbn hostname\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((he = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
        herror("gethostbyname");
        return 2;
    }
    printf("domain name is: %s\n", he->h_name);
    printf("    IP addresses: ");
    addr_list = (struct in_addr **)he->h_addr_list;
    for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s ", inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

run command:

gcc -o test test.c
./test www.google.com

Output:
domain name is: google.com
IP addresses: 172.217.163.110
```